# Migration from Adwords PHP Sdk 19 to 32 - How to dynamically call services

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am facing the challenge to migrate a whole application based on the now outdated Adwords PHP Sdk 19 to the new 32 version.

One of the cores of my application is that I dynamically call the Adwords services as they are needed.

```
$customerService = $adwordsClient->GetService($nameOfTheService);
```

that would translate to, for ex:

```
$customerService = $this->GetService('CustomerService');
```

This also gave me the convenience of not needing to import all the classes on my code. But with the new SDK, it works like this:

```
$customerService = $this->adWordsServices->get($this->adWordsSession, CustomerService::class);
```

So it is not possible to write

```
$nameOfTheService::class
```

Because dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time in php.
Also, PHP will force me to import before hand every class that will be invoked like this.

Any ideas on how to make this work in an elegant and efficient way?

Comment: If you know the name of the service you require in various parts of your application, why don't you just replace that `string` name with the FQ class namespace instead?

Comment: Well, this makes me spread "use" statements all over the code. I came up with the below class the helps me to keep my code organized. Thanks anyway @fubar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ones trying to organize your Adwords PHP plug, here is a helpful class to keep invoking the classes with strings. Remember to change the v201705 for the version you are using and also check any Service changes on newer versions.

```
<?php
use Exception;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\mcm\AccountLabelService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\AdCustomizerFeedService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\AdGroupAdService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\AdGroupBidModifierService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\AdGroupCriterionService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\AdGroupExtensionSettingService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\AdGroupFeedService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\AdGroupService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\AdParamService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\rm\AdwordsUserListService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\BatchJobOpsService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\BatchJobService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\BiddingStrategyService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\billing\BudgetOrderService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\BudgetService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\CampaignBidModifierService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\CampaignCriterionService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\CampaignExtensionSettingService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\CampaignFeedService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\CampaignGroupPerformanceTargetService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\CampaignGroupService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\CampaignService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\CampaignSharedSetService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\ConversionTrackerService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\CustomerExtensionSettingService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\mcm\CustomerService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\ch\CustomerSyncService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\DataService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\DraftAsyncErrorService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\DraftService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\FeedItemService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\FeedMappingService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\FeedService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\LabelService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\LocationCriterionService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\mcm\ManagedCustomerService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\MediaService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\OfflineCallConversionFeedService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\OfflineConversionFeedService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\ReportDefinitionService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\SharedCriterionService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\SharedSetService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\o\TargetingIdeaService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\o\TrafficEstimatorService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\TrialAsyncErrorService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\TrialService;

class AdwordsServicesList
{
    private static $serviceList = [
        "AccountLabelService" => AccountLabelService::class,
        "AdCustomizerFeedService" => AdCustomizerFeedService::class,
        "AdGroupAdService" => AdGroupAdService::class,
        "AdGroupBidModifierService" => AdGroupBidModifierService::class,
        "AdGroupCriterionService" => AdGroupCriterionService::class,
        "AdGroupExtensionSettingService" => AdGroupExtensionSettingService::class,
        "AdGroupFeedService" => AdGroupFeedService::class,
        "AdGroupService" => AdGroupService::class,
        "AdParamService" => AdParamService::class,
        "AdwordsUserListService" => AdwordsUserListService::class,
        "BatchJobOpsService" => BatchJobOpsService::class,
        "BatchJobService" => BatchJobService::class,
        "BiddingStrategyService" => BiddingStrategyService::class,
        "BudgetOrderService" => BudgetOrderService::class,
        "BudgetService" => BudgetService::class,
        "CampaignBidModifierService" => CampaignBidModifierService::class,
        "CampaignCriterionService" => CampaignCriterionService::class,
        "CampaignExtensionSettingService" => CampaignExtensionSettingService::class,
        "CampaignFeedService" => CampaignFeedService::class,
        "CampaignGroupPerformanceTargetService" => CampaignGroupPerformanceTargetService::class,
        "CampaignGroupService" => CampaignGroupService::class,
        "CampaignService" => CampaignService::class,
        "CampaignSharedSetService" => CampaignSharedSetService::class,
        "ConversionTrackerService" => ConversionTrackerService::class,
        "CustomerExtensionSettingService" => CustomerExtensionSettingService::class,
        "CustomerFeedService" => CustomerFeedService::class,
        "CustomerService" => CustomerService::class,
        "CustomerSyncService" => CustomerSyncService::class,
        "DataService" => DataService::class,
        "DraftAsyncErrorService" => DraftAsyncErrorService::class,
        "DraftService" => DraftService::class,
        "FeedItemService" => FeedItemService::class,
        "FeedMappingService" => FeedMappingService::class,
        "FeedService" => FeedService::class,
        "LabelService" => LabelService::class,
        "LocationCriterionService" => LocationCriterionService::class,
        "ManagedCustomerService" => ManagedCustomerService::class,
        "MediaService" => MediaService::class,
        "OfflineCallConversionFeedService" => OfflineCallConversionFeedService::class,
        "OfflineConversionFeedService" => OfflineConversionFeedService::class,
        "ReportDefinitionService" => ReportDefinitionService::class,
        "SharedCriterionService" => SharedCriterionService::class,
        "SharedSetService" => SharedSetService::class,
        "TargetingIdeaService" => TargetingIdeaService::class,
        "TrafficEstimatorService" => TrafficEstimatorService::class,
        "TrialAsyncErrorService" => TrialAsyncErrorService::class,
        "TrialService" => TrialService::class
    ];

    static function get(string $name)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($name, self::$serviceList)) {
            throw new Exception("This AdWords Service does not exist. :(");
        }

        return self::$serviceList[$name];
    }
}
```